# How do I turn echo off under MinTTY?

Tags: c, windows, shell, mintty

I have a program that is running under MinTTY (cygwin's shell) and calls to `GetConsoleMode`/`SetConsoleMode` fail. `_getch` echos to the console as well. This is a native win32 app without bindings to the cygwin environment, so any cygwin functions are out. How do I turn off the echo so that I can input a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I essentially emulated the following via `popen`:

```
save_state=$(stty -g)

/bin/echo -n "Account: "
read acct
/bin/echo -n "Password: "
stty -echo
read password # this won't echo
stty "$save_state"

echo ""
echo account = $acct and password = $password
Read more at http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_read_password_without_echoing_c.html#Z3FtcTtMHe0gJdES.99
```